# Force Generic Type to match function definition

Tags: typescript, generics

Is it possible to force a generic type to not only be of type `Function`, but to also match a specific function definition?

For example, the closest way I have come up with is:

```
class MyClass<T = (S : any, E : EventArgs) => void> {
    ...
}
```

This of course works, but it doesn't not force this type, it is just the default type. I can do both

```
let myClass = new MyClass<string>();
```

or

```
let myClass = newClass<(any, number) => void>();
```

Both of which I do not want to be possible. I want the type to always match the function definition of `(any, EventArgs) => void`.

Is this possible in TypeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. To define [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) `extends` keyword should be used:

```
class MyClass<T extends (S: any, E: EventArgs) => void> {
     // ...
}
```

As you've already figured out, `=` specifies a [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) for generic type parameter.